# Viewing images full screen using $scope ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to view my images in full screen using css, but when I use ng-repeat it doesn't display it. I'm looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54849694/10933255 but I can't run it using arrays in $scope.

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.newImg = ["https://picsum.photos/200",
                     "https://picsum.photos/200/300/"]
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
<div ng-repeat="image in newImg" class="fill">
  <img ng-src="{{image}}">
</div>
```

Comment: You have not added any click handler on your image, what are you expecting to happen on click?